# Set rich-text into Xperido template

Tags: java, xperido

I dont know if somebody here use Xperido for document generation.

What I want to achieve is, using that service, send a rich-text as string and set into the template and keep all the format of the document.

I guess It would be like attach an HTML into the document

Comment: Hi Paul, XperiDo has the ability to keep source formatting inside the Word Add-in. Did you checked that option already? If you add a mapping in your template, you can go to the Mappings tab and double click the mapping. The properties window will open and you can find a tab Rules and there you can select and play with Preserve formatted text.

Comment: Good point, yes I´m using XPerido template on word. I´m gonna take a look of that thanks!!!

Comment: @TimVK I did what you told me and I put in my mapper the rule preserve fromatted text, and then the option html. I sending in the xml the html as String. But then when I generate the document I see this line instead the formatted text. Failed to insert data from URL. Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the version of the XperiDo Word Add-in (About in the XperiDo ribbon)? And maybe the XML or piece of it where you think the problem might be? It looks like it is searching for a site from a URL (which is probably not provided?)

Comment: My fault!, I already make it works as you explain to me. Thanks a lot mister!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out!

Comment: @TimVK I have another question mister. Do you know, how can I attach one template to other page, and use the mappers there?.

Comment: Paul, I do not completely understand this question but I know when you have the same dataset over templates, you can copy/paste the contents of the first template to the second one and the mappings will remain there. If this is not what you wanted, could you please describe your question in more detail please?

Comment: @TimVK I have another question, I´m trying to create a sanity check againt Xperido and I would like to retrieve the XSD that Xperido has. to compare with that I have on the server. But in the API of Xperido as far as I see there´s no way to get those XSD